# Loading external javascript in a Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy

I'm trying to load some external javascript code in my Chrome extension.  However, due to the sandboxed environment of the extension, I can't see any of the functions defined by the external code.

The external code implements a dependency mechanism, whereby one javascript file may require another, and so forth.  It also looks at arguments to the URL used to load the javascript to determine the top level javascript file to load.  So it basically is able to load any arbitrary web app, and it is not known in advance all the files that will be used.  So I can't use any static definitions in the extension.

There is also the issue that since all extension code is sandboxed, I don't have complete access to the document - for instance, it can't access the window variable.

But if I put all the code in the external code, I run into content security problems if one script tries to load another.  The whole reason I went was an extension is because of the bone-headed misimplementation of CSP by every single browser in existence whereby bookmarklets can't access external resources.

What's the best practice for bypassing or working around the extension sandbox to basically be able to run code as if the page itself had loaded it, without any issues with CSP?

Answer (score 0):

In the content script you could do something like this to load the js file

```
function inject(url, exteral) {
    // 1. Build the absolute URL
    // 2. Create a script tag and set src attribute
    // 3. Append script tag to thw window
    if (!external){
       url = chrome.extension.getURL(url);
    }
    var scriptElement = document.createElement('script');
    scriptElement.src = url;
    (document.body || document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(scriptElement);
}
```

If the js file is packged with the extension, it must be placed in the
`manifest.json` under [web_accesible_resources](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources).
othwerwise it need to have the same protocol that the page it is injected in `(http | https)`

Since the content script is not allowed to call the window functions, you could 
call [window.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) to send data from the actual window to content script.

Comment: I can't package the js files with the extension... which one and how many of them isn't fixed, and packaging them would inhibit automatically using the latest version.

Comment: Just tested with an external url and it also works, you can provide any url to inject, it just need to be the same protocol. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: If I create the script tag and insert it into the document, it gets fouled up by CSP when it tries to load additional javascript files...

Comment: I've made a [gist](https://gist.github.com/leon19/631740b868f18e185287) it's currently working for me

Comment: Now from the gist try creating another script tag and giving it a second URL on the same domain, and then try to run the extension from github.com. `Refused to load the script 'https://localhost/test2.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src assets-cdn.github.com collector-cdn.github.com"`