# Using CDN Javascript libraries in Chrome extensions (manifest v3)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, jsdelivr

I have a simple Chrome extension that analyzes the page using ChatGPT and creates Google Calendar invite. The full source is [here](https://github.com/pathikrit/chrome_ai) but here's the core of the code which reads the current page's text when clicked:

`manifest.json`:

```json
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Chrome AI",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "index.html",
    "default_icon": "chrome_ai.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "activeTab",
    "scripting",
    "storage"
  ],
  "host_permissions": ["<all_urls>"]
}
```

`index.html`:

```json
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Chrome AI</title>
    <script src="vendors/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script defer src="index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="gcal">Create Google Calendar Invite</button>
<code id="logs"></code>
</body>
</html>
```

`index.js`

```js
$('#gcal').on('click', executeInTab(() => document.body.innerText).then(text => $('#logs').append(text)))

executeInTab = (f) => chrome.tabs.query({active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true})
  .then(([tab]) => chrome.scripting.executeScript({target: {tabId: tab.id}, function: f}))
  .then(([{ result }]) =>  result)
```

But, as you can see this requires me to download and check in `jquery` under `vendors/jquery-3.7.1.min.js`. Since [it is a bad practice to check in library dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29674006/is-it-good-practice-to-store-binary-dependencies-in-source-control) to your repo (same reason you don't checkin your `node_modules`), I prefer to simply use a CDN like `jsdelivr` to host my libraries. But, when I try to add  `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.4/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>` I get following error:

**Before someone closes this question as a duplicate, here is why other answers don't work:**

1. In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34950009/) the accepted answer is for manifest v2 whereas I am on [manifest v3](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/migrating/). The v3 answers posted there simply don't work (my code posted here does the suggestion from there).
2. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12035242/loading-jquery-into-chrome-extension) asks how to load the jquery into the active tab window and not really as a dependency of the extension itself
3. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37609783/chrome-extension-how-to-include-library-in-content-and-background-scripts-from), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53029697/how-to-include-library-in-extension-in-chrome), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29189641/loading-external-javascript-in-a-chrome-extension) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45379920/loading-libraries-for-use-in-a-content-script) asks how to load libraries into the content and background workers and not into the popup window itself. FWIW, these are duplicates of each other and NOT duplicate of this question!
4. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70977030/how-to-use-cdns-for-google-chrome-extension-and-not-violate-the-content-securit) one is poorly phrased and has no answers and uses manifest v2

Comment: Using index.js is correct but you also need to do the same for jquery - put it into the same folder and load it the same way. ManifestV3 extensions can't use external code, so you can remove `content_security_policy`. Don't forget to remove your inline `<script>` too and note that the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu.

Comment: @wOxxOm: But isn't it bad practice to check-in libraries? Why can't I just import from CDN?

Comment: Extensions are a part of the browser so they must be available offline.

Comment: @wOxxOm: That makes no sense. Look at the ChatGPT Chrome extension - how would it work offline? It makes ajax calls to OpenAI!

Comment: The files necessary to display the UI must be local to ensure at least the UI works offline.

Comment: @wOxxOm: Still makes no sense - what if my UI has a link to an image on the internet? If I am offline that image won't load and my UI would be broken. You are saying such extensions are not allowed but they clearly are (e.g. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rakuten-get-cash-back-for/chhjbpecpncaggjpdakmflnfcopglcmi)

Comment: In that case your UI is not offline-friendly. It's not forbidden though. External scripts are intentionally forbidden in ManifestV3. I tried to guess the reasons behind this restriction, that's all. Another reason is the increased security as any external URL can be spoofed even if it's https since you don't use Subresource Integrity.

Comment: > In that case your UI is not offline-friendly. 
Well, it is a _web browser_ extension (web = internet)

But seriously, there should be a solution to this involving a package manager like gulp or bower which can materialize a fully offline extension given dependencies

Comment: If you import the file using `import` statement (instead of using a script tag) and install the npm package, it should be automatically handled by the bundler.

Comment: @wOxxOm: That's a good idea. Can you answer this question and I will accept the answer. Also, someone marked this as a duplicate - I don't think its right. Can you click on "reopen" also?

Comment: Indeed, after editing the question has become a jQuery-only problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to improve security, Chrome has [removed support for CDNs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/migrating/improve-security/#remove-remote-code) in extensions with Manifest V3, or any other way of using remotely hosted JavaScript.

They have a few solutions they recommend instead:

- You can also load external libraries at runtime by adding them to the files array when calling `scripting.executeScript()`. You can still load data remotely at runtime:

  ```js
  chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: {tabId: tab.id},
    files: ['jquery.min.js']
  });
  ```
- Just bundle the file as part of the extension. I know this is viewed as bad practice according to the article you found, but it has a minimal impact for the user, and the Chrome documentation doesn't seem to have a problem with it.

  ```html
  <script src="./jquery.min.js"></script>
  ```